# What does the maximum number of possible concurrent requests in JBoss AS depend on?

Tags: jboss

Like the title days: does the maximum number of requests JBoss AS can serve per second depend on the OS configuration (number of connections, threads, etc.), or are there some theoretical limits in the AS self?

I am not talking about setting these limits myself, with JBoss parameters like maxThreads, but about limitations that cannot be overcome by tweaking and optimizing the AS.

Comment: @Downvoter who did not comment: please improve my question if it's wrong, or close it if it's not fit for SO. If it's a RTFM kind of question, please at least point me to the FM ;-) A downvote without explanation does not tell me anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what type of request you are talking about.  I will assume HTTP requests.  If so then the max number of requests or threads is calculated as (32 times the number of processors available to the Java virtual machine.)

If it is another type of request, please clarify.